# Spring ActiveMQ use JDBC with tcp

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Given the fact that the only requirement I have is to use an instance of ActiveMQ, how would I make my ActiveMQ to use a JDBC connection without creating a embedded one with VM transport.

This is my factory bean:

```
@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    logger.info("ActiveMQConnectionFactory");
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(15000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(-1);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
}
```

I have an image of activemq exposed in the URL: tcp//0.0.0.0:61616 but even with the JDBC adapter configured as shown below I'm not able to persist messages in the SQL server, activemq is ingoring this and use the KahaDB as default. The only way  found to use the jdbc is to change from tcp to vm:localhost but this creates an embedded activemq.

```
@Bean
public BrokerService broker(DataSource dataSource, ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory) throws Exception {
    logger.info("BrokerService");
    final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    JDBCPersistenceAdapter jdbc = new JDBCPersistenceAdapter(dataSource, new OpenWireFormat());
    jdbc.setUseLock(true);
    Statements statements = jdbc.getStatements();
    statements.setBinaryDataType(BINARY_DATA_TYPE);
    broker.setUseJmx(true);
    broker.setPersistent(true);
    broker.setPersistenceAdapter(jdbc);
    broker.addConnector(format("vm:(broker:(tcp://localhost:61616,network:static:%s)?persistent=true)", brokerUrl));
    logger.info("BrokerService URL: " + broker.getTransportConnectors().get(0).getConnectUri().toString());
    return broker;
}
```

Comment: Try using a standalone broker with proper XML broker configuration.  What do the logs say?  How are you sending message?  Not enough details here.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using xml file to configure the broker. Easier to manage vs coding up a broker.

ActiveMQ JDBC info:
ref: https://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-support

Persistence Adapter info:
ref: https://activemq.apache.org/persistence

Starting an embedded broker referencing an xml file:
ref: https://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference

specifically:

```
vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml
```